How do you evolve trade Pokémon on Let's Go Pikachu/Eevee?
I would like to know how to evolve Pokémon via trade, such as Machoke into Machamp on Let's Go Pikachu/Eevee.
Currently, I have 2 Nintendo Switches, a digital copy of both games on the same Nintendo log in account.
How do I trade and evolve Pokémon?

Prerequisites
You cannot use 2 digital copies of the game to trade!
You will not be able to log into your account on 2 digital copies at the same time. I needed to purchase an additional physical copy of Let's Go: Pikachu. However, I am able to use a the digital copy of Let's Go: Eevee.
Equipment used:

Nintendo Switch x2 (I used an OLED and a lite)
Digital copy of Let's Go: Eevee and physical copy of Let's Go: Pikachu

Method
You can do this on local link between both consoles.
On both games, do the following:

Go to the main menu and press the communicate icon
Press play with others
Press "Nearby Player"
Press "Link Trade"
Click the same 3 Pokémon on the link code page
Select the Pokémon you want to offer as a trade
Then trade them

If you want to trade the Pokémon back, just follow a subsection of the above steps to trade them back.
